# DevExpress MVVM: custom interface

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

I'm searching a way to do what for me would be simple without mvvm, but I'm working with this pattern, and so...

I have a gridcontrol, where I load a set of records. Then, when user click, I populated a propertyGridControl It works, but the result is... so... ugly!!

[image]

I have made an image of my wanted result:

[image]

In this second image, as you can see, user can edit the data, with field grouped in mini areas.

Which is best way to change from first picture to the second, respecting the mvvm pattern? User interface? template? or what? are there any working example?

Comment: Is it possible to create an userControl like in the second Picture, and then load it to your gridControl?

Comment: what you see in the pictures in already a usercontrol, but I think it is possible.. but how, respecting the mvvm criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my control where I load custom propertyGrid. It has element DockSite(actipro element) where I bind custom propertyGrid:

```
<docking:DockSite viewModels:DockSiteViewModelBehavior.IsManaged="true" CanDocumentWindowsRaft="True" ItemContainerRetentionMode="Wrapped"
                      DocumentItemsSource="{Binding DocumentItems}"
                      ToolItemsSource="{Binding ToolItems}"/>
```

In in the viewModel (in constructor) I just add my propertyGrid:

```
_toolItems.Add(new PropertyGridToolWindow
                         {
                             Title = "Properties",
                             ViewModel = {DefaultDock = Dock.Right, DockGroup = "2", IsInitiallyAutoHidden = true}
                         });
```

and _toolItems are:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<PropertyGridToolWindow> _toolItems = new ObservableCollection<PropertyGridToolWindow>();
```

Comment: you are binding a collection, but in this case I need to bind only one object per time. The entire collection is in the gridcontrol (where user selects the object to see in detail)

further, what is documentitems in your code?

Comment: Document windows can be defined by binding the DockSite.DocumentItemsSource property to a collection of items, such as view-models. The items will be wrapped in an instance of DocumentWindow, which is used to present the item. I just needed that to my Project and forgot to delete. I am not sure, but I think it's not a Problem that you will bind only one uc, later, if you will Need to add another control, you will Need only to add a new control to this collection